# Permission Set Question

Tags: permission-sets

Permission Set users have Create/Read/Edit permission to an Object.

Permission Set users have access to Apex controller using the Object.

Controller uses a Custom Setting which restricts values which controls certain action of the controller e.g if a certain picklist value of Field A is selected , then show error/invoke webservice .

If a value of that picklist field is added to the Custom Setting , does it have any impact on the permission set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your custom setting was of the hierarchy type, and I suspect you have a custom setting of type list, the picklist value will simply be a "value", not a field on anything other than the custom setting. So, unless you restricted the access to it when displayed either through your controller or the visualforce page, there would be no affect on the permission set.

Comment: Thanks. Yes , the custom Settings is of List Type. On a sidenote , does FLS precede Permission set?

Comment: Permission set opens up or extends access to records beyond what's set by OWD for FLS. A permission set cannot make access to records more restrictive than existing FLS as set under OWD.